# Para que serve cada componente de um projeto Android?

Tags: android

Estou começando agora no desenvolvimento Android, e estou com dúvidas quanto aos diretórios do Android Studio, eu preciso entender para que serve cada um deles para o projeto.
Confesso que nunca programei em uma linguagem com tantos diretórios(app, manifests, res, drawable, layout, values, minimap e etc), arquivos(Todos os XML) e classes(Classe R por exemplo).
Eu preciso saber para que serve cada arquivo, classe e diretório, e o AndroidManifest.xml? Esses foram somente exemplos, se possível me ajudem com todos os componentes de um projeto, tenho certeza que esta é a dúvida de muitos.

Comment: Creio que sua duvida é muito ampla, explicar todos os arquivos assim como você espera, demandaria uma resposta grande e complexa. Talvez focando em itens mais especificos ajude a ter uma resposta satisfatória.

Comment: Talvez este links te ajudem mais do que uma resposta aqui: [Criando um projeto Android e entendendo sua estrutura](http://bolivaramancio.com.br/criando-projeto-android-entendendo-estrutura/), [A pasta “res” e os resources em um projeto Android](http://tableless.com.br/a-pasta-res-e-os-resources-em-um-projeto-android/) e [ESTRUTURA DE UM PROJETO EM ANDROID](http://www.thiagocury.eti.br/disciplinas/android/estrutura-projeto-android.php)

Answer (score 3):

**`app`**         =   Todo o contexto do seu aplicativo.

**`manifests`**   =   Diretrizes principais do seu app (aqui você fará configurações com caráter global e afins).

**`res`**         =   Pasta que contém layout, `drawable` e muito mais.

**`drawable`**    =    Normalmente deve se colocar as imagens ai dentro, cada imagem dentro de sua pasta, que é definida pelo tamanho da imagem (1 imagem deve ter vários tamanhos para se adequar em várias telas).

**`layout`**   =   O corpo do seu App, o `XML` de *config* das telas estão ai.

**`values`**   = Normalmente tem as pastas, `@Strings`, `@Colors`, `@Dimens` e *uma outra que eu não lembro*.

**`Strings`**  = Deve conter todos os textos que será visível em seu A.pp (onde se aplica a tradução).

**`Colors`**   = O próprio nome já fala tudo, ai vc trabalha as cores de tudo.

**`Dimens`**  = Onde você poderá definir dimensões padrão e aplicar em diversos lugares (vale para as outras pastas também).

Mas assim não é o melhor jeito de conhecer um ambiente de desenvolvimento, sem contar que ainda tem **MUITA** coisa a ser vista.

Comment: Valeu meu amigo!
Muito legal!